# How to add a property to reduce function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this code:

```
    source.map(data =>
      /*tslint:disable:no-string-literal*/
      Object['values'](
        data.reduce(
          (acc, { name, type, count }) => 
            (((acc[name] = acc[name] || { name })[type] = count), acc),
          {},
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

This code outputs this:

```
  {
    "name": "name1",
    "type": "type1",
    "size": 2,
    "total": 4
  },
```

I want to add one more property to the output so it looks like that:

```
  {
    "name": "name1",
    "type": "type1",
    "size": 2,
    "total": 4,
    "newProp": 'value'
  },
```

The new prop is a hardcoded prop so it wont come from the `source.`.

What is the best way to do that?

---

After playing with a code turned out that I had to take the `newProp` value from the `source.`

```
source.map(data =>
      /*tslint:disable:no-string-literal*/
      Object['values'](
        data.reduce(
          (acc, { name, type, count, newProp }) => 
            (((acc[name] = acc[name] || { name })[type] = count), acc), //how would you assign a newProp value here? 
          {},
        ),
      ),
    ),
```

How would you assign a `newProp` value within a reduce funcion?

Comment: The best solution would probably be assigning it after the `Reduce` call. If it is explicitly not from `source`, then assigning it in `Reduce` is an anti-pattern.

Comment: maybe `data.map(d => d["newProp"] = "value").reduce((acc, { name, type, count }) => ( ... ))`?

Comment: I was wrong, the value is coming from the `source.`, updated the question

Comment: The given code wouldn't produce the given result. The reduce function does not return the accumulator but the value of count, so it would result in a number. Please give a working version with a minimal input example that leads to the result.